# should I send win form control as parameter?

Tags: c#, user-interface, parameter-passing

A winform **forms.cs** contains a gridview. This gridview(many columns) get populated with an xml elements and its attributes.

Another class "**XMLReader.cs**" that reads XML file and returns

```
List <someclassObjects>
```

Now I am sending gridview  as a parameter from **form.cs** to another class "**UpdateAppUI.cs**" that receives the Gridview as parameter and update it.

**Question is:** Is there any issues with passing controls as parameter? Experienced professionals said donnnn't pass controls.

Then How I can access form controls to other classes?

What is the solution for above situation?

Comment: Why can't you pass List<SomeClassObject> ?

Comment: I am passing, but binding grid view with list, I want to do in separate class...

Comment: Is there any specific reason to do so?

Comment: hmmm yes, Actually there are many components(classes) in solution. Now I need to do intrgration with mainform.cs... intergrating in mainform might make some issues. So I want to create a class that handle alll integration work, and from **mainform.cs** i have to handle that single class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you want to pass the grid view?

If simply you want to update it in UpdateAppUI.cs file then pass the datafrom gridview in the datatable. And from datatable you can update the database from the class.

No need to pass the control.

If you really want to pass the datagrid then create new object of datagrid as same as yours and pass that as an parameter.

Comment: I think he wants to break out bits and pieces of his code to make it more modular and readable. That's very common. But once you do, you need to re-think some other aspects so that the design isn't over-engineered.

Comment: @bhavik.... yes that I can do. But that looks like adding  another thing between grid and List. I can populate grid with list, then Y data table to be used? what issues comes if I pass gridview as param

Comment: @filip, Yes application became too modular, facing trouble while integrate.

Comment: that also is a gud to use <listview> if your data can be managed in that. And passing a gridview also doesn't require, but if you pass the gridview than also it will not create an issue.

Comment: Ok... it was not answer that satisfied me very well but, I am happy to get alternative solution. I think there are some mistakes in my planning. Anyways Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I think that what those developers are refering to is: avoid making your UI unrepsonsive. You might want to look at your design ( read: conceptual model / design diagram ) before your deside how to implement this functionality.

There's an article on MSDN covering ["Give .NET Apps a Fast and Responsive UI with Multiple Threads"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300429.aspx).

Consider this, if you have a Parent form that needs to update its child controls you might want to make the whole form accessable by the "update helper". But then again, try not to make to much heavy lifting on the UI Thread.

Also remember that your controls are `Objects` and when `Objects` are passed as parameters they are sent as  [`reference types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) so another "danger" is that your method might do something malicious to your control.

To make the design understandable and manageable by others as well, I would step back one step and think about the design of your software.